# Redirection issue following migration from Node.js app to static site on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, static-site

I plan to migrate my personal blog presently using Node.js as a backend to Amazon S3, considering the fact that the content is pretty much always static.

One problem I noticed is that there's no way to do redirection or whatsoever on Amazon S3 (as far as I know).

Lets say I have this URL:

`http://blogue.jpmonette.net/2013/06/11/hebergez-vos-applications-nodejs-grace-a-digitalocean`

When I'll migrate it to Amazon, I'll have to create this folder hierarchy:

`/2013/06/11/hebergez-vos-applications-nodejs-grace-a-digitalocean/`

and then add the file `index.html` in it, containing the data.

Considering this, my URL will then be changed from:

`http://blogue.jpmonette.net/2013/06/11/hebergez-vos-applications-nodejs-grace-a-digitalocean`

to

`http://blogue.jpmonette.net/2013/06/11/hebergez-vos-applications-nodejs-grace-a-digitalocean/`

There's no way to redirect that right now using Amazon S3.

Also, anyone requesting `http://blogue.jpmonette.net/2013/06/11/hebergez-vos-applications-nodejs-grace-a-digitalocean/index.html` will obtain a file, and this is annoying in term of SEO.

Is there an available solution to prevent this behavior and preserve good SEO of my blog?

**EDIT**

And for people flagging it as not appropriate question, I'm looking here to make proper permanent redirection on Amazon S3, to make sure that visitors looking for articles in the future will find them. Please note here that visitor includes humans and robots.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: It's more about making proper permanent redirection on Amazon S3, because not doing so will have a negative impact on my SEO and people might end up on the wrong page.

Comment: Click on the tag and read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like we can create redirection rules this way (for `a-propos` to `a-propos/`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>a-propos</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>a-propos/</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Considering I have a ton of URL to redirect (83 in total), it seems impossible to do because there's a limit of redirection rule:

`83 routing rules provided, the number of routing rules in a website configuration is limited to 50.`

---

Other then that, the only option I see is to add this HTTP header `x-amz-website-redirect-location` to a file with the same name as your prior URL.

For the example above, create a file named `a-propos` and add the HTTP header `x-amz-website-redirect-location` and put `a-propos/` as a value. This should work, but it takes forever to do.

---

Syntax can be found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax

Rule generator can be found here:
http://quiet-cove-8872.herokuapp.com/